# How update variable within another class

Tags: python, class

I have these classes :

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player("name")


    class Turn():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def end(self):
            #how update xp player

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.xp = 0
```

And my question is how when turn is terminated, how update the player

Comment: You seem to be omitting `def` from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these classes are in the same module you can define a global variable in the module that can be used in both classes. Otherwise you need to explicitly pass the variable on the instances of both classes.

Comment: This is a bad example for a global variable*. `Game`, `Turn` and `Player` should reference each other and attributes should be updated via these references. (* does not mean a good one exists)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Game` class appears to have a reference to a player in its `self.player` attribute. If you want to update that player's `xp` attribute, you can do something like this:

```
def end(self):
    self.player.xp += 5
```